# Authenticating with AWS .NET SDK for Amazon Chime

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-chime-sdk, sts, amazon-chime

I'm trying to create meeting using Chime SDK and I'm passing accessKey and accessKeyId to authenticate. However, the request fails with error, 'Invalid session token'. When I pass session token generated using AWS CLI it works fine. I want to generate the session token programmatically from within .net. How to achieve this.

```
AWSCredentials credentials = new Chime.Credentials(awsAccessKeyId, awsSecretAccessKey, token);
RegionEndpoint region = RegionEndpoint.USEast1;
        client = new AmazonChimeClient(credentials, RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
CreateMeetingRequest request = new CreateMeetingRequest();
        request.MeetingHostId = meetingHostId;
        request.ExternalMeetingId = externalMeetingId;

        return await client.CreateMeetingAsync(request);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting the ClientRequestToken

```
CreateMeetingRequest request = new CreateMeetingRequest();
request.MeetingHostId = meetingHostId;
request.ExternalMeetingId = externalMeetingId;
//needs request.ClientRequestToken = ????
```

Tim